# What is the alternative of $apply in AngularJS Component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

When I remove items from items list. It takes time to refresh on the browser. I am unable to found any alternate of $apply(). It's a callback function when call the component object from outside the component.

```
import template from './itemListItems.html';

export const name = 'itemListItems';
export const itemListItems = {
    template,
    bindings: {
        listItems: '<',
        addNewItem: '&',
        editItem: '&',
    },
    controller: class ItemListItemsController {
        // @ngInject
        constructor(page) {
            this.page = page;
        }
        removeItem(indx) {
            var func = function (button) {
                if (button === 1) {
                    this.listItems.splice(indx, 1);// After removing itemlist, 
it takes few seconds to refresh on browser.                
                  }
            };
            navigator.notification.confirm(
                'Are you sure you want to remove this item?',
                func.bind(this),
                'Confirm Delete',
                ['Confirm', 'Cancel']
            );
        }
    }
};
```

I have issue on this line. **this.listItems.splice(indx, 1);**
After removing itemlist, it takes few seconds to refresh on browser. Previously in directove mode, I was using $scope.$apply(). But in component, $apply is no more available. What is the solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to refresh the page.
If you already initialize the array in the parent component, it should update automatically, since the array is a reference type.

The better way, is to use '&' binding, like your 'addNewItem' and 'editItem'.

It should look like this:

```
export const itemListItems = {
    template,
    bindings: {
        listItems: '<',
        addNewItem: '&',
        editItem: '&',
        onRemove:'&',
    },
    controller: class ItemListItemsController {
        // @ngInject
        constructor(page) {
            this.page = page;
        }
        removeItem(indx) {
            var func = function (button) {
                if (button === 1) {
                    this.listItems.splice(indx, 1);
                    this.onRemove(indx);

                  }
            };
            navigator.notification.confirm(
                'Are you sure you want to remove this item?',
                func.bind(this),
                'Confirm Delete',
                ['Confirm', 'Cancel']
            );
        }
    }
};
```

**Parent- HTML:**

```
<item-list-items list-items="yourlist" on-remove="removeFromList($event)"></item-list-items>
```

**Parent-controller js:**

```
//...
$scope.removeFromList = function (index) {
    $scope.yourlist.splice(index, 1)
}
//...
```